# How do I make a "iterable variable"?

Tags: python

I want to make a variable that can be changed iterably through for loops, as in:

```
for i in range(15):
  var + i = 12
```

so that when it is finished, there will be 15 variables that has the number 12. I've done this through code.org (I'm taking computer science) and I want to know if this is possible through python.

Comment: Don't do this use a *container* like a list or a dict

Comment: Do you mean creating 15 different variables for each iteration? Could you store the items in a list?

Comment: You can dynamically create variables in the global scope, but not in a local scope. It is almost **never** a good practice, however

Answer (score 1):

Like that?

```
g = globals()
for i in range(15):
    g[f'var{i}'] = 12
```

It can be useful for practise, to understand how variables storing. In real projects you should use some sort of collections. Usually list or dict.

Comment: Yes that might work! Thank you!

Comment: @AbnormalHare822 please don't actually do this, it is a terrible practice

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga updated answer with this info.

Comment: @Alpensin I'm using it for list lists. Oops I solved my problem aaaaaa